# Assign a different proxy to thread - Java

Tags: java, multithreading, proxy

Hi Guys I am making a bot which can use a an other REST API to create a user but API only supports one user at a time and I dont want to change it. So I am using Multithreading to call the API multiple times, but I want to use proxies in it. So like different proxies for different threads, and all the threads use `HttpClient` and I tried its `#proxy` method and gave it the `ip` and `port` of the proxy but when I tried to call the API it returned a `null` response and I tried without the proxy and it did return a valid response.

So is there any other way to assign an proxy to a thread
My Code

```java
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder()
                .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1)
                .followRedirects(HttpClient.Redirect.NORMAL)
                //THIS LINE BELOW IS HOW I USED PROXIES
                .proxy(ProxySelector.of(new InetSocketAddress("proxy.example.com", 80)))
                .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
                .build();
HttpRequest discordAccNoCaptcha = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create("https://myapiserver.com/api/v9/auth/register"))
                .timeout(Duration.ofMinutes(2))
                .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(body))
                .build();
        String response = client.send(discordAccNoCaptcha, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString()).body(); /* This is null when using ProxySelector and valid response when using no ProxySelector */
```

Comment: Show the actual failing code with the proxy logic

Comment: Hello @ErwinBolwidt I have edited the post you can see

Comment: You're getting the body without checking the status code of the response. What is the statusCode() in both cases? Only 200-299 indicate an OK response.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt The status code is 400

Comment: 400 means "Bad Request". It may mean that you "proxy" isn't actually a proxy server and doesn't understand proxying requests.

Comment: How do you access the proxy server? (I am trying to not let the server know i am the same guy, thats why I am using a proxy)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241024/discussion-between-vinesh-rajpurohit-and-erwin-bolwidt).